# Displaying elements of a Generic Tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I am trying to display all elements of this Generic Tree, in the fashion -

NodeData --> (list of all the children data)

According to the input given, my output should be-

10-->5,6

5-->4,1

6-->

4-->

1-->

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong, my o/p is only 10--> for some reason.
I've written a recursive code for printing the generic tree. Please help me out..
My code is :

`````
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    vector<Node> children;
};

void printTree(Node *node)
{
    cout<<node->data<<"-->";
    for(auto x:node->children)
    cout<<x.data<<",";
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    for(auto x:node->children)
    printTree(&x);
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={10,5,4,-1,1,-1,-1,6,-1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    
    stack<Node> s;
    Node root;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==-1)
        s.pop();
        else
        {
            Node temp;
            temp.data=a[i];
            if(s.size()==0)
            {
                root=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                s.top().children.push_back(temp);
            }
            
            s.push(temp);
        }
    }
    
    printTree(&root);

    return 0;
}````
`````

Comment: `root` object was never on the stack `s`; nothing was ever added to its `children` member. If you print `root.children.size()`, you'll see it's zero. Realize that `root` and `temp` are two distinct `Node` objects; `root=temp;` doesn't magically glue them together, it just copies the current contents of `temp` to `root`. Subsequent changes to `temp` aren't automatically reflected in `root`, as you appear to 
expect.

Comment: when elements `-1` are encountered you `pop` from the stack but don't update childrens, its not quite clear what the expected output is

Comment: So how do I glue them together? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To print your tree you need to have a pointer to the top of the tree which is what `root` is meant to be. To fix root so that it can reference the top of the top tree, make root to a pointer type (`Node *`). Then when you set `root = &temp`, root will point to the top of your tree rather than just a copy of the top node.

Your code declares `root` as an un-instantiated object. As such, `root = temp` triggers a shallow copy of `temp` into `root` at the time of execution. After the copy is done, changes to `temp` are not reflected in `root` because they are distinctly separate objects. Although it should be noted that if the objects were to have pointer type properties, then the pointers would be copied and thus both object would have a separate pointer to the same memory space.